# [solved] gazebo_plugins in ROS fuerte: permission denied

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have a weird problem when I add as dependency gazebo_plugins in a package built with ROS fuerte. If a add this dependency in a manifest.xml like the following one

Contains plugins for Gazebo.

```
<author>Neostek</author>
<license>BSD</license>
<review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
<url>http://ros.org/wiki/diffDrive3d</url>
<depend package="roscpp"/>
<depend package="gazebo"/>
<depend package="gazebo_plugins"/>

<export>
    <gazebo plugin_path="${prefix}/lib" />
</export>
```

and I compile my package ros tells me the following

### [rosmake-1] Starting >>> gazebo_plugins [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 2 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir: cannot create "build" directory : Permission denied

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package gazebo_plugins written to:

If I remove that dependency everything goes fine.

I need this dependency since this package is also suited for ROS electric that needs that, otherwise it cannot find folders like odometry and more.

Does anyone has the same problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance for any responce,

Neostek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47237/%5Bsolved%5D-gazebo_plugins-in-ros-fuerte:-permission-denied/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-07**:
It seems to be the problem of gazebo_plugins package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem. I do not know why there is no NO_BUILD file in gazebo plugin packagem then ROS tries to compile that package that is in /opt where it has no permission. If you reset the file, then everything is fine.

---

Originally posted by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) with karma: 156 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-08**:
Never change any files in /opt. That is really bad, not only because your changed files will be overwritten by the next update. Instead, always create an overlay. See http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays